# Automatically adding decimal values to number in EditText

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an EditText where the user wants to enter the price. In order to maintain uniformity, I decided to automatically include the decimal values.

Hence `"1" entered by user would become "1.00"` for example.

Now, after working with my inefficient code, I can across a better code in StackOverFlow

```
    amountEditText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))
        {
            String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
            StringBuilder cashAmountBuilder = new StringBuilder(userInput);

            while (cashAmountBuilder.length() > 3 && cashAmountBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
                cashAmountBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
            }
            while (cashAmountBuilder.length() < 3) {
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '0');
            }
            cashAmountBuilder.insert(cashAmountBuilder.length()-2, '.');
            cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '$');

            amountEditText.setText(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
            // keeps the cursor always to the right
            Selection.setSelection(amountEditText.getText(), cashAmountBuilder.toString().length());

        }

    }
});
```

With the above code, the decimal value starts getting included once the user starts entering the number. But, the numerical value added by the user will be displayed with `$ symbol`. Hence, I made a little modification to the code in Line 07 and deleted Line 19.

**The new code is**

```
        returnPrice.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
    returnPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().matches("^(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$"))
            {
                String userInput= ""+s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                StringBuilder cashAmountBuilder = new StringBuilder(userInput);

                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() > 3 && cashAmountBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
                    cashAmountBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
                }
                while (cashAmountBuilder.length() < 3) {
                    cashAmountBuilder.insert(0, '0');
                }
                cashAmountBuilder.insert(cashAmountBuilder.length()-2, '.');

                returnPrice.setText(cashAmountBuilder.toString());
                // keeps the cursor always to the right
                Selection.setSelection(returnPrice.getText(), cashAmountBuilder.toString().length());

            }
        }
    });
```

**My Problem**

So  the problem I am facing in case 02 is, when I am entering the numeric value in EditText - unless I am entering the decimal dot, the numeric value in EditText gets displayed as an integer.

**For example : Case 01**

For displaying 100.00 as I go on typing, the value starts displaying as $0.01, then $0.10, then $1.00, $10.00 and finally $100.00. At any instance, I don't need to enter a decimal dot manually in this case.

**For example : Case 02**

For displaying 100.00 as I go on typing, the value starts displaying as 1, then 10, then 100. Now, if I press the decimal dot on soft keyboard, the 100 becomes 1.00 and on typing the value turns 10.00 and finally 100.00. If the decimal dot is not touched on the keyboard, the resulting value on entering 10000 is 10000 and not 100.00.

What's the error I made? Any suggestions?

Comment: For this kind of problem I suggest you use the debugger to step through the code line by line to isolate exactly where things start to go wrong.

Comment: why not format the value to a float once the editing is done, you can use DecimalFormat to format the value to two digits decimal value.  Let me know if you want me to add an example